# Количество вариантов расстановки клеток

Tags: c++, алгоритм

В зоомагазине нужно расставить в один ряд клетки с кошками и собаками. В ряд помещается N клеток, при этом есть одно ограничение: нельзя ставить подряд три клетки с животными одного вида (иначе они передерутся). Предполагается, что в магазине есть неограниченное количество клеток с кошками и собаками. Определите, сколькими безопасными способами можно расставить N клеток в ряд.

Входные данные
Входная строка содержит одно натуральное число – количество клеток в ряду N .

Выходные данные
Программа должна вывести количество безопасных способов расстановки N клеток в ряд.

Примеры
входные данные
5
выходные данные
16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для двух клеток возможны следующие варианты: СС, СК, КС, КК, придадим им индексы 0..3

Для следующей клетки вариант, оканчиваюшийся на СС, возможен только, если собаку добавить к варианту КС. Вариант, оканчиваюшийся на СК, возможен только, если кошку добавить к варианту СС или КС. Вариант, оканчиваюшийся на КС, возможен только, если собаку добавить к варианту СК или КК. Вариант, оканчиваюшийся на КК, возможен только, если кошку добавить к варианту СК.

Получаем соотношения для i от 3 до N

```
    LL[i][0] = LL[i-1][2]
    LL[i][1] = LL[i-1][0]+LL[i-1][2]
    LL[i][2] = LL[i-1][1]+LL[i-1][3]
    LL[i][3] = LL[i-1][1]
```

И в конце считаем результат - сумму `LL[N]` как `LL[N][0]+LL[N][1]+LL[N][2]+LL[N][3]`

Внимательно всматриваемся в результаты для разных `N`: `4 6 10 16 26 42 68 110...` и видим удвоенные [числа Фибоначчи](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%87%D0%B8)

```
Result(N) = 2*Fib[N-1]
```

что позволяет ещё упростить решение и даже решить задачу для довольно больших `N`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int N=5;
    long long Old = 0;
    long long Fib = 1;
    long long Temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        Temp = Fib;
        Fib += Old;
        Old = Temp;
    }
    std::cout << 2*Fib;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: т е это просто вставляем в цикл for от i = 3 до N, а в конце считаем сумму LL[N] это как?

Comment: Да, вторую строку руками заполняем единицами, и цикл. В конце `LL[N][0]+LL[N][1]+LL[N][2]+LL[N][3]`. Или с Фибоначчи, как я дописал - это еще проще.

Comment: Чтобы показать свой код, можно редактировать свой вопрос здесь же. Я добавил код через Фибоначчи.